# TCL Opaque Handle C lib

Tags: c, tcl

I am confused with the following code from [tcl wiki 1089](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/1089),

```c
#define TEMPBUFSIZE 256 /* usually enough space! */
char buf[[TEMPBUFSIZE]];
```

I was curious and I tried to compile the above syntax in gcc & armcc, both fails. I was looking to understand how tcl handle to file pointer mechanism works to solve the chaos on data logging by multiple jobs running in a same folder [log files unique to jobs].

I have multiple tcl scripts running in parallel as LSF Jobs each using a log file. 
For example,
    Job1 -> log1.txt 
    Job2 -> log2.txt 
    (file write in both case is "intermittent" over the entire job execution)
Some of the text which I expect to be part of log1.txt is written to log2.txt and vice versa randomly. I have tried with "fconfigure $fp -buffering none", the behaviour still persists. One important note, all the LSF jobs are submitted from the same folder and if I submit the jobs from individual folder, the log files dont have text write from other job. I would like the jobs to be executed from same folder to reduce space consumption from repeating the resource in different folder.

Question1:
Can anyone advice me how the tcl "handles" is interpreted to a pointer to the memory allocated for the log file? I have mentioned intermitent because of the following, "Tcl maps this string internally to an open file pointer when it is time for the interpreter to do some file I/O against that particular file - wiki 1089"
Question2:
Is there a possiblity that two different "open" can end up having same "file"?

Comment: This syntax is invalid, try using single brackets

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for swift reply, I have taken form http://wiki.tcl.tk/1089. I am trying to figure out why simple file write from tcl script running as lsf job ends up having data from another lsf job(tcl script) running in parallel. FYI i have a schedular which continues keeps certain number of jobs running. maybe the new job ends up creating same "file"[0-9]* string? how can i avoid this?

Comment: @hariprasath if you have another question then do ask another question. Anyway, it is clear from the code that it is some kind of mistake in the original code related to it being posted into a forum / wiki, thus the doubling of brackets.

Comment: @Antti, I have updated my question. I am quite new to this forum, sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: @hariprasath I mean please post your other question as a *separate* post. [This 4th revision should be added as another question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43517815/4)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the line, the code has been mangled; it looks like it happened when I converted the syntax from one type of highlighting scheme to another in 2011. Oops! My original content used:

```c
char buf[TEMPBUFSIZE];
```

and that's what you should use. (I've updated the wiki page to fix this.)

Comment: [As I suspected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517815/tcl-opaque-handle-c-lib?noredirect=1#comment74089886_43517815)